# Use "SCNView" instead of "ARSCNView" – when it's not supported

Tags: objective-c, swift, scenekit, arkit, arscnview

I need to show 3D model via ARKit using `ARSCNView`, however, if user has an unsupported device A8- or iOS version 10-, so the app would use `SCNView`.

Is it possible to maintain that in one `ViewController` and `Storyboard`?

How should I init sceneView in Objective-C?

```
if (ARConfiguration.isSupported) {
      // use ARSCNView
} else {
      // use SCNView
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In storyboard use `ARSCNView` and add to your `ViewController` fallback to `SCNView`:

```
override func loadView() {
    if (!ARConfiguration.isSupported) {
        print("ARKit not supported, using SCNView")
        view = SCNView(frame: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 640, height: 480))
    } else {
        super.loadView() // Use ARSCNView from storyboard
    }
}
```